# How to send Request in android facebook 3.5 api?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I am making an android application in which I have to send request to friends of user.

I am using following link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/

it is working correctly it show `dialog` with friends allows selecting people and sending request. but request is not received on receiver end.

Can any body help me it will be really helpful.

Comment: Are you getting the "Request sent "toast message?

Comment: People can see the received request with notification only if they  have the same app installed on android device and facebook application is also installed there. If you do define canvas for your app and put some content there, then request notifications will be shown in the facebook web page. Still, even if canvas isn't defined you should see the request appears in the App Center tab.

Comment: @sromku please make it answer so i can accept it and also if you can share how i can reciever can recieve notification

Comment: @Nitin thanks, I answered :) Regarding the notification, once you send the request to the user, he/she gets the notification automatically after few minutes or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People can see the received request with notification only if they have the same app installed on android device and facebook application is also installed there. If you do define canvas for your app and put some content there, then request notifications will be shown in the facebook web page.

Still, even if canvas isn't defined you should see the request appears in the App Center tab.